# HTML table like `ls`

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

Is it possible to create an HTML/CSS Table that is formatted like the POSIX [`ls`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls)?  That is, entries are displayed alphabetically in columns, where the number of columns is dependent on the width of each column?

For example, see in this screenshot how the columns are only as wide as necessary. The fourth column is much wider than than the others, and the third column is narrowest of all as all its file names are short. There are four columns in this screenshot but there could be more if the terminal were wider and fewer if it were narrower.

[image: ls screenshot]

The number of columns varies based on the width of the terminal and the exact file names in the listing. As more file names are shown, more columns are added. Once the right side of the terminal is reached, `ls` makes the columns taller. If there are lots of short file names there could be a lot of columns, whereas if the file names are long there would be fewer.

Comment: use `<div>` with fixed css width and `display:inline-block`

Comment: How can the number of columns increase or decrease based on column width in a table?

Comment: its the default functionality on `table' element. You need not to do anything for setting column width according to no. of characters.Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Xk2zz/

Comment: I've added a screenshot to hopefully make the question clearer. It would be easy to simulate `ls -l`'s output, but doing something like plain `ls` is actually rather difficult.

Comment: OP has to confirm if this is his requirement. He says "where the number of columns is dependent on the width of each column". he does not specify anything about the having each column with different width

Comment: @JohnKugelman: have you checked the jsfiddle linked?

Comment: Sounds like [multi-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts) but with a responsive number of columns. Not sure this is possible if the the string widths are variable without some scripting.

Comment: @SajithNair each column should fit the width of the longest text in that column.  Thanks John Kugelman for the screenshot depicting this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the good-news is that browsers "sorta" support this with table elements and [`table-layout:auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) rendering (this should be the default, and is after an appropriate CSS reset). The bad news is it's only "sorta".

For starters, you *must* pick the number of columns and render the HTML table such that the items are in the correct column - this includes all sorting! Then, if you don't over-constrain the width of any column in the table, make sure the table is `table-layout:auto`, and set the width of the table then the results should [be similar to](http://jsfiddle.net/3fgFL/1/) that of ls - that is, the columns will "automatically adjust width" based on the content.

To get an "identical" result to ls would require something more heavy-handed, such as using a fixed-font (like that used in a terminal) and manually calculating the column widths (like ls does), perhaps in a <pre> element. CSS/HTML has limitations that ls simply avoids by doing layout calculations itself against a fixed-width terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This is a table as any other. Unless there is something else you didn't specify. You may do something like this

```
<table>
<colgroup style="width:22%"></colgroup>
<colgroup style="width:25%"></colgroup>
<colgroup style="width:25%"></colgroup>
<colgroup style="width:25%"></colgroup>
<colgroup style="width:3%"></colgroup>       
<thead>
     <tr>
    <th>Closed Day</th>
    <th><span>|</span>Is this a paid day?</th>
    <th><span>|</span>Last updated date</th>
    <th><span>|</span>Last updated by</th>
    <th><span>|</span>Current?</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>08/10/2013</td>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>02/12/2014</td>
        <td>c-jsmith</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>09/01/2013</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>02/12/2014</td>
        <td>c-kkearney</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12/25/2013</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>01/12/2014</td>
        <td>c-jjohnson</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12/26/2013</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
        <td>02/01/2014</td>
        <td>c-gthompson</td>
        <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Using a table similar to above and the script below with some modifications you should be able to limit the amount of rows and stack to the right with positioning.

```
         <script>
           function tableWrap() {
              var maxRows = 10;

              var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
              var wrapper = table.parentNode;
              var tableRows = table.rows.length;
              var height = 0;
                if (tableRows > maxRows) {
                   for (var i = 0; i < maxRows; i++) {
                      height += table.rows[i].Height;
                   }
                      wrapper.style.height = height + "px";
                 }
               }
         </script>
```

Comment: See the screenshot I added. Your answer is more akin to `ls -l` than plain `ls`.

Comment: Let me see if I understand, as more data is being printed out, more columns are created and the table grows horizontally?

Comment: That's right. More columns will be added until the right side of the terminal is reached. At that point `ls` makes the columns taller and taller.

Comment: I edited my answer. I created something similar for an EKG screen for a client. You may be able to use it and modify as needed. But the logic is pretty much there in the script. Use dynamic positioning with a if-statement to document.write to the right as needed

Comment: I couldn't understand how this works, so I put it in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kTssL/ .  It doesn't make fewer columns if I have a thinner window (and it doesn't make more columns if I have a wide window).

Comment: I thought you said you needed to expand to the right as more columns are entered..hmmmmm. .In that case, I'd use responsiveness. Set the table to 100% width (make sure you have a responsive framework or use [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) and the table should respond to the screen width

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get something started with javascript:

```
var outer = document.getElementById("outer");

function setColumns(n) {
    var style = outer.style;
    style.columnCount = n;
    style.MozColumnCount = n;
    style.WebkitColumnCount = n;
}
var i = 1;
while (outer.scrollWidth <= outer.offsetWidth) {
    setColumns(++i);
}
setColumns(i - 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jEq4R/2/

It doesn't handle the width, yet, but it at least gives a good number of columns.

**EDIT**: works in firefox but not webkit

Comment: i can't seem to change the width of each column separately: http://jsfiddle.net/jEq4R/3/

Answer (score -1):

Adjust the width in this jsfiddle and see http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/DdqfA/

**HTML**

```
<div>column</div><div>column</div><div>column</div>
<div>column</div><div>column</div><div>column</div>
<div>column</div><div>column</div><div>column</div>
<div>column</div><div>column</div><div>column</div>
<div>column</div><div>column</div><div>column</div>
<div>column</div><div>column</div><div>column</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Please read the question he wants the number of columns to be adjusted based on column width

Comment: Why? can you please explain?

Comment: This does not size the columns based on the contents. `ls` will use wider columns if the file names are long.

Comment: @SajithNair I see what you're getting at. Still, make sure to reduce the scope of the styling applied - applying it to all divs is most definitely not correct, and it won't allow any column to be narrow or wider.

Comment: This is just an example, When using in a page we can always have an outer div with a class